# Difference between 32bit <> 64bit and serial communication

Tags: vb.net, 64-bit, serial-port

I'am using the Rs232 Class Library in a vb.net application to print text to a POS printer.
in the last week some of our clients have upgraded their system to Windows 7 x64 bits versions and start to fail when they print text via COM to the printer.
Can anyone help me regarding this? Is there anything special you have to do with a 64bit enviorment when using the Rs232 library or is it the application itself that needs modification?

Comment: What error are you getting? If none, what happens?

Comment: The thrown exception im getting is "Write command error". it occurs in the CRs232.vb If Marshal.GetLastWin32Error <> ERROR_IO_PENDING Then Throw New ApplicationException("Write command error") Else ,thankyou for your time!

Comment: http://files.codes-sources.com/fichier.aspx?id=38418&f=send+SMS%5CCRs232.vb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in the serial port support for x64 Win7.  The COM port is however very likely to be either missing or at another port number.  Your customer will need to use Device Manager to find the correct port number.

Comment: There is no problem opening the COMport, i think.. Excepetion "Write Command Error." is thrown.

Comment: Write Command Error doesn't mean anything.  You are going to have to improve your error handling.  What is the value of LastWin32Error()?  And use the System.IO.Ports.SerialPort class.

Comment: Thanks Nobugz, so you say i should rather use the  System.IO.Ports.SerialPort instead of CRs232.vb?

Comment: Yeah, always prefer a standard .NET class over a custom wrapper.  For one, it is much more likely to give you a good exception that tells you what is really wrong if there's a problem.

Comment: Cheers man, I will give that a try!

thankyou so much for your time. i will let you know how it goes

Comment: Hello again!, i have tested with the System.IO.Ports.SerialPort instead of CRs232 on a 64bit computer but get the following result.

"The given port name does not start
with COM/com or does not resolve to a valid serial port"

i have checked and doublechecked in the Device Manager i even set the .PortName to to is SerialPort.GetPortNames(0)

same code works just FINE on my station.

Comment: I dunno, sounds like my original post was accurate.  Is this some kind of USB device?  Try another one.

Comment: Hey Nobugz! there was some sort of ghostprinter installed on the COMport. i restarted the computers and they all now work just fine!!

i just want to say it it all worked by swapping out the CRs232.vb to System.IO.Ports.SerialPort made it 64bit compatible.

thankyou once again Nobugz (:

Answer (score 0):

Old post but adding a solution for anyone searching in the future.  I'm not certain of the root cause of this, but compiling your application strictly for x86 will fix this issue.

`Project > YourProject Properties... > Compile tab > Advanced Compile Options... > Choose x86`

You should use `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` in the framework going forward though.